convert object literal notation to dot notation for mongoose
In NodeJS I receive from Postman an object like:
sysData: {
  status: 'active'
}

This needs to be dynamically converted to dot notation like
{ 'sysData.status': 'active' } so I can do a find with Mongoose.
The object can change. How do I convert this dynamically?
In Postman I have created a Query Params following sysData.status, however, I don't receive this in NodeJS. When I create a Query params following SysData[status] I receive this in NodeJS in object literal notation, which in my opinion I can't use for Mongoose. So I need to convert this. Because the Query params can change, this needs to be done dynamically.
Or is there another way to resolve this?

what goes wrong?

Please share details on how your request looks like on the client side and how your request handler looks like on the server side ...

curl 'localhost:8080?foo.bar=baz' seems to work fine, ie the req.query in the backend is { "foo.bar": "baz"} as expected

Does this answer your question? Best way to flatten JS object (keys and values) to a single depth array

This question would be useful to future users if you paste in a sample document from your database that was not being found using {sysData: {status: 'active'}} but was found using { 'sysData.status': 'active' }.

Problem:
Given an object passed from postman of:
{ sysData: { status: 'active'} }

When used in a mongoose query like so:
Model.find({ sysData: { status: 'active'} })

It will match this document:
//Document 1
{
   name: 'bob',
   age: 21,
   sysData: { status: 'active' }
}

But not this document:
//Document 2
{
   name: 'sally',
   age: 60,
   sysData: { status: 'active', cores: 4 }
}

The reason this happens is because when your query object is defined like so:
{ sysData: { status: 'active'} }

MongoDB will look for an exact match for sysData. The implications are that if you have another key in the sysData object in your database (e.g. cores: 4) then there won't be an exact match.
However, when you define your query object like this:
{ 'sysData.status': 'active' }

MongoDB will find both documents above because the query is only looking for a document where the sysData.status object has a value of active. All other keys are irrelevant.
Solution:
There are many ways to transform your postman object into the desired format. One way could be by using Object.entries() with Object.keys and Object.values() like so:
const postman = { sysData: { status: 'active'} };
let query = {};
const key = `${Object.keys(postman)[0]}.${Object.keys(Object.entries(postman)[0][1])[0]}`;
const value = Object.values(Object.entries(postman)[0][1])[0];
query[key] = value;
Model.find(query);


Ohh so dot notation provides exact match but object literal notation doesn’t. Why is there no canonical reference for this or did I miss it? This is something of great importance. +1 for a good answer.

@ChukwujiobiCanon it's the other way around. Dot notation is only concerned with matching the specified keyA.keyB: value whereas object literal keyA:{keyB:value} is asking MongoDB to match exactly the object {keyB:value}.
